# Add an input value to label on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

```
      var descriptionInput;
     var tbl = document.getElementById('21.125-mrss-cont-none-content');
Array.from(tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr')).forEach(function(tr) {
  Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll("input[name$='6#if']")).forEach(function(input) {
    input.onkeypress = function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        descriptionInput = input.value;
        input.value = descriptionInput;
        document.getElementById('__AGIM0:U:1:4:2:1:1::0:14').value = descriptionInput;
      }
      console.log(descriptionInput);
    }
  });
});
// if value of __AGIM0:U:1:4:2:1:1::0:14 != New Item can add new row to top of table.
// get table
var table = document.getElementById('DYN_6000-LISTSAPLMEGUI-tab');
var t = table.rows.length;
//getting current blank cell ID and upping the blank cell ID to the new last cell
var new_cell_id = table.rows.item(t - 1).id;
var old_cell_id = "DYN_6000-LISTSAPLMEGUI-key-" + t;
table.rows.item(t - 1).id = old_cell_id;
table.rows.item(t - 1).onmouseover = function() {
  showItemDetailDropDown_hover(old_cell_id);
};
table.rows.item(t - 1).onmouseout = function() {
  showItemDetailDropDown_hover(old_cell_id);
};
table.rows.item(t - 1).onclick = function() {
  showItemDetailDropDown_click(old_cell_id);
};
//create new row and table
var drop_down_height = document.getElementById('DYN_6000-LISTSAPLMEGUI-scrl').style.height;
document.getElementById('DYN_6000-LISTSAPLMEGUI-scrl').style.height = (parseInt(drop_down_height.replace("px", "")) + 18) + "px";
var new_row = table.insertRow(t - 1);
var new_cell = new_row.insertCell(0);
new_row.insertCell(1);
//set new row and cell properties
new_row.id = new_cell_id;
new_row.classList.add('urNoUserSelect');
new_row.style.width = "100%";
new_row.style.height = "18px";
new_row.onmouseover = function() {
  showItemDetailDropDown_hover(new_cell_id);
};
new_row.onmouseout = function() {
  showItemDetailDropDown_hover(new_cell_id);
};
new_row.onclick = function() {
  showItemDetailDropDown_click(new_cell_id);
};
new_cell.classList.add('urIlb2I');
new_cell.classList.add('urColorTxtStandard');
var new_item = t;
new_cell.innerHTML = "[ " + new_item + " ]";
var zyx = "grid#21.125#" + row + ",2#if";
document.getElementById(zyx).value = new_item;
document.getElementById('__AGIM0:U:1:4:2:1:1::0:14').value = new_cell.innerHTML;
checkButton('keyboard');
```

The first function gets an input from every row in a column (descriptionInput). The second part builds an item dropdown menu from a table in JS. The dropdown menu displays [ 1 ] - [ 10 ] depending on which row the user inputs information into. How do I add the user input to the label like

> [ 1 ] descriptionInput
>   ?

The input should go after "new_cell.innerHTML" and added to the label at the bottom with long ID ("AGIM0:")
I'm thinking I could create a string right before it writes the value to the field and set it to the string, or do item[x].itemnumber + item[x].descriptionInput but I don't know how to write it correctly.

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: There's just too much code to put in jfiddle